# Cordova multiapp

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi there the situation is this currently we have two apps one for online work and other for offline.
I was wondering could we put one of the apps in a folder in WWW folder of cordova and with different index.html to chose which one to load, so at the end we end up wit only one application which houses those two and you can switch them based on that index.html.

Comment: Ummm... you could do a redirect from index.html to index-online.html or index-offline.html based on the value of `navigator.onLine`?

Comment: Thanks, a path worth to try. I'll post info when we try that approach. Thanks again.